# Using checkboxes to pass multiple strings to array in migration with ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox, database-schema, rails-migrations

Im looking to have a user create a post where they specify what instruments they play. There should be a checkbox for each instrument so the user can select the ones that apply to the post. I was able to display the instruments and their checkboxes in the post creation but I cannot figure out how to save them to the post. I get error ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch.

Displaying all instruments and passing integers for each (Id like to pass strings)

```
  <% Instrument.all.each do |instrument| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "post[instruments][]", instrument.id %>
    <%= instrument.name %> <br>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
```

Migration to receive array of integers

```
class AddTagsToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :posts, :instruments, :integer, array: true, :default => []
  end
end
```

schema.rb

```
 create_table "instruments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "category_id"
    t.string "title"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "account_id"
    t.integer "instruments", default: [], array: true
    t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_posts_on_account_id"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_posts_on_category_id"
  end
```

post.rb model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :instruments
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }

end
```

instrument.rb model

```
class Instrument < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :posts, optional: true
end
```

Private end of the posts_controller.rb

```
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def post_params
      params.fetch(:post, {}).permit(:title, :content, :category_id, instruments:[])
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your controller to your question? That's likely where the problem is.

Comment: Please add the actual full error message from the web server console with the request sent by the client.

Comment: Also you only added the private methods of the controller, the error is in your create/save method please post the create method in the controller.

Comment: Also you have associations that probably won't work. You can't have a belongs_to Post if the Post model doesn't have instruments_id, and Post can't have has_many Instruments without some sort of post_id on instrument. I think you need to look at a join table with `has_many through:`.

Comment: You can do without the relations and just put a method in Post.rb that gets/sets the instrument IDs as the array.

Comment: I highly recommend you watch this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised